# Capture images in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, opencv, webgl

I am working on Image Processing projects.

I want to capture the images(Face) from the web-camera using web browser and i am not allowed to install any additional plug-ins.

Currently, i am using Flex/Flash to capture the images.As per the requirement, i am also not allowed to use Flex/Flash.

Is there any package to capture images from webcamera?

Note: Actually, i want to apply some image processing algorithms like face Detection , filters at browser end. I will be good if the same package used for image capturing has some image processing algorithms.

Updated by author of the post:
Can anybody tell me the possibility with webgl?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to let users take a snapshot of themselves with the webcam, that's possible with `capture=camera` in one line  using HTML5's`getUserMedia/Stream` API. here is how:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Supported in latest chrome, firefox & opera.  for others, flash or other plugins are the only option.

Link:  [can I use webcam](http://caniuse.com/stream)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to do with Webgl?

Comment: You should be able to use the captured camera image to create a WebGL texture.

Answer (score 1):

As Gaurish mentions, `getUserMedia` is what you can use for this, although its cross-browser support is not guaranteed.

To see how you can use this, and canvas to get the image, take a look at [Filtering a webcam using getUserMedia and HTML5 canvas](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/filtering-a-webcam-using-getusermedia-and-html5-canvas) which uses it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to do with Webgl?

Comment: Why would you want to use WebGL?

Comment: Post capturing, i want to process the image before sending to the server. Would like to know the possibilities with Webgl? What kind of process: Grey Scale conversion, rotation, cropping.

Comment: Process it in what way? What do you want or need to do with it? I'm just wondering if you can do what you need in the canvas since the image is already there this saving yourself trouble (but you can use WebGL on canvas items, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL)